# Why object initialization and destroy should be done in user-defined function?

Tags: c++

In some C++ projects, object initialization destruction is handled by user-defined functions rather than by `constructors` and `destructors`.

```
class A  
{
public:
    A();
    virtual ~A();

    void Initialize(){
        // do some real object initialization here
    };
    void CleanUp(){
        // do some real object destroy here
    }
}
```

Here are some reasons I can give why should we do that:

- [Lazy initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization), to improve the performance
- virtual method cannot be used in constructor and destructor
- There is no parameters in desturctor and it cannot be override
- No exception could be thrown in constructor and destructor

I want to know is there any other cases should we do object initialization and destroy in user-defined function?

Comment: This reminds me the 3dsMax SDK which uses the member function `void DeleteThis() { delete this; }` in all its objects :)

Comment: My old boss insisted on this style. That's why he's no longer my boss.

Comment: No, "we" don't do that, because "we" know it is a terrible idea.

Comment: Plus one, just because the idea in the question is terrible doesn't mean the *question* is terrible.

Comment: I think we should vote the question, not the idea. But, maybe, the wording of the question can be designed to distance yourself from the bad idea.

Comment: @NickyC Maybe "we do" can be misinterpreted as suggesting this is accepted practice, but I think OP means this is done in some specific projects.

Comment: People actually write code this way in more than one project? I would have thought the horror was lesson enough once! BTW, you *can* (and sometimes *should*) throw from a constructor.

Comment: If you do `throw` from a constructor then note well that the destructor is not called. After a couple of nights' bug fixing, you never forget that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a dreadful anti-pattern.

1. A constructor will always run in one thread. That's useful. Don't discard that.
2. The object will be in an undefined state between construction and initialisation.
3. You will have to control the thread safety of `Initialize` yourself.
4. All the base class construction will take place before `Initialize`: that's beyond your control.
5. Any base class destruction will take place after `CleanUp`: that's beyond your control.
6. You will have to control the thread safety of `CleanUp` yourself.
7. The object is in an undefined state between `CleanUp` and destruction.
8. The destructor will always run in one thread. That's useful. Don't discard that.

(1) and (8) are particularly important; exactly one thread will call the constructor and destructor. They are conducive to achieving program stability.

Comment: I believe you can easily run the destructor from more than a single thread (by calling `delete` on a pointer or even explicitly calling the destructor on an `auto` object.) Is there a guarantee in the language somewhere that I don't know about?

Comment: 1 and 8 are totally irrelevant; there's no reason for construction and initialization to occur in different threads.  The only real drawback with this pattern is your point 2.

Comment: Possibly not sufficiently clear but two threads calling `Initialize` could cause trouble. Point 7 is equally important to point 2 by symmetry.